# Function not returning the value of the chosen folder from msoFileDialogFolderPicker

Tags: excel, vb.net, vsto, office-addins, excel-addins

I'm working on a new excel VSTO add-in and I want to get the chosen folder by using a custom function since I'll be reusing this function a lot.

However I am getting this error because the Function is not returning a value.
**Warning   BC42105 Function 'GetwkbDestSavetoPath' doesn't return a value on all code paths.** Is there something I'm missing in here?

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon
Imports Microsoft.Office.Core
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Public Class Ribbon1
    Dim wkbSource As Workbook
    Dim wkbDest As Workbook
    Dim shDest As Worksheet
    Dim fso As Global.System.Object
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Dim DestPath As String
    
    Private Function GetwkbDestSavetoPath() As String
        fldr = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.FileDialog(MsoFileDialogType.msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        With fldr
            .Title = "Select a Folder where to save the file"
            .ButtonName = "Select"
            .AllowMultiSelect = False
            If .Show <> -1 Then Exit Function
            DestPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
        End With
        Return DestPath
    End Function
    

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the following line of code should be changed to return any value like an empty string:

```
If .Show <> -1 Then Exit Function
```

So, just try to return `String.Empty` instead:

```
If .Show <> -1 Then Return String.Empty
```